# Rails 4 - how to add an edit link for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, nested-routes

I'm trying to figure out nested routes.

I have models called Project and Potential Use. The associations are:

Project

```
has_many :potential_uses
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :potential_uses, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Potential Use

```
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
```

In my projects show, I'm trying to loop through each potential use.

```
<% @project.potential_uses.each do |pu| %>
      <div class="row">
            <p><%= pu.comment %></p>
            <strong><%= pu.user.formal_name %></strong>
              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_potential_use_path(pu) %>

            <p style= 'border-bottom: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px'></p> 

      </div>    
    <% end %>
```

When i try this edit link, I get an error that says:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"potential_uses", :id=>nil, :project_id=>#<PotentialUse id: 14, comment: "asdf", project_id: 17, created_at: "2016-08-19 01:36:49", updated_at: "2016-08-19 01:36:49", user_id: 1, private_comment: false>} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I've tried several different versions of the edit link.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_potential_use_path(potential_use) %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_potential_use_path(project.potential_use) %>
```

I can't find a way that works.

My rake routes, shows this for the edit action:

```
edit_project_potential_use GET       /projects/:project_id/potential_uses/:id/edit(.:format)     potential_uses#edit
```

To my eye, this looks like I need to ask for plural references to the resources in the edit link (although it doesnt make sense to me), like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_projects_potential_uses_path(pu) %>
```

That formulation gives this error:

```
undefined method `edit_projects_potential_uses_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd4b7431b18>:0x007fd4b7430678>
Did you mean?  edit_project_potential_use_path
               edit_project_potential_use_url
```

I can't see how to take this information and use it to write an edit link.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify a parent too:

```
edit_project_potential_use_path(@project, pu)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your rake routes, I think it the path should be `edit_project_potential_use_path(@project, pu)`

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_potential_use_path(@project, pu) %>
```